# Disconnect from Intuit App center

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are facing issues while disconnecting app from Intuit App center.
When we do disconnect, our disconnect servlet is getting called but parameters are null.
From the forums we understood that  disconnect landing URL should be OpenID enabled to get the information like realmId, username. In our case we are not implementing OpenId since 
we don't want to publish in the Intuit App Center. So how we will get the details
such as realmID of disconnected company when disconnect from Intuit App center. Is it possible to get those details without implementing OpenId while disconnection from Intuit app center?

Comment: Until you will not add the code how can one find out the problem.

Comment: we just want to know whether it is possible or not to get the details without implementing openId in our app first ?

Answer (score 2):

Realm id, email and user name are only provided through AX or SREG params. If OpenID is not implemented, you would not be able to retrieve those values.